# Re-create global link for npm package

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a conflicting node package and Ruby gem that lives in `/usr/local/bin`. Instead of re-installing the node package every time I wish to create the `/usr/local/bin/package` link, is there a command such as

```
npm install package --bin-links
```

that will only create the global link?

https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-install.html shows there is a `--no-bin-links` option and https://www.npmjs.org/doc/files/npm-folders.html explains the folder structure, and I fail to find any options to only re-link a global node package.